# Can we do multiple substitutions with a single Perl command?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to make the following into one `perl -pe` instead of piping it in sequence?

```
cat text.txt | perl -pe "s/PATTERN1/$PATTERN1/g" | perl -pe "s/PATTERN2/$PATTERN2/g"
```

Comment: `perl -pe "s/PATTERN1/$PATTERN1/g; s/PATTERN2/$PATTERN2/g"`

Comment: This needs to be `perl -pe "s/PATTERN1/\$PATTERN1/g; s/PATTERN2/\$PATTERN2/g"` otherwise it will simply delete `PATTERN1` and  `PATTERN2`.

Comment: @Borodin You are right, of course. Please feel free to make proper answer of it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that Mark Setchell posted in the comments is perfect:

```
perl -pe 's/PATTERN1/$PATTERN1/g; s/PATTERN2/$PATTERN2/g' text.txt
```

But here's a goofy way to do it just for fun:

```
perl -pe '$_ = s/PATTERN1/$PATTERN1/gr =~ s/PATTERN2/$PATTERN2/gr' text.txt
```

Anyway, so you don't need to use pipes at all. Just add the file name as the last argument.